# WCF Client Configuration in a Sharepoint Webpart

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wcf-client

I have a Sharepoint 2010 webpart that calls a WCF service.

I've created a service proxy and manually coded the endpoint, see below.

In a conventional WCF client I'd use the config files for the configuration and use transforms when I was buiding for deployment to different environments.

How would I achieve the same through a Sharepoint webpart? I want to put the configuration somewhere that it can be changed for different build configurations.

ie. For a local deployment during testing, then a test server, production. We're trying to automate this as much as possible.

Thanks,
Tim

**UPDATE:**
I'm aware that you need to put config data in the web.config file in sharepoint. I'm looking for a way to put these config settings into source control and have them automatically populate / deploy for different builds and environments.

> namespace CombinedPortal.WcfClient {
>       public class FrameworkServiceProxy : IFrameworkService
>       {
>           private IFrameworkService _proxy;
>
> ```
>     public FrameworkServiceProxy()
>     {
>         var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://server:1234/FrameworkService.svc");
>         var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
>
>         _proxy = new ChannelFactory<IFrameworkService>(binding, endpoint).CreateChannel();
>     }
>
>     public Framework GetCurrentFramework(double uniqueLearnerNumber)
>     {
>         var fw = _proxy.GetCurrentFramework(uniqueLearnerNumber);
>         return fw;
>     }
> } }
> ```

Comment: You could access your SharePoint's web.config to get the keys you need, and set those up in the all the environments you will deploy it. Is this automated enough?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is C# code which executes on the server.

When then user presses a button on a web part there is a POST back to the Sharepoint web server, where the C# code executes.

It is therefore the web.config of your SharePoint site which is used.